# How to make an accessible and writtable array into other method

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I have an array :

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
     [...] 
     String[] a = new String[x] ; 
     double[] b = new double[x] ; 
     [...]
}
```

I want to creat a method, and this method must load this array
(this method is in the same file/class)

```
public void datain() {
     [...]
     System.out.println( "Valor test:" + b[0] ) ;  
     [...]
}
```

Is it possible?
Is possible to make changes into array "a" or "b", within the datain method ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two simple ways to achieve your goal.

First, you can move your arrays one level up and make them static fields of your class.

```
static String[] a;
static double[] b;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    a = new String[x] ;
    b = new double[x] ;
}

public void datain() {
    System.out.println( "Valor test:" + b[0] ) ;
}
```

This will work, but it is generally bad approach to modify static fields from non-static methods.

Second, you can pass your arrays as arguments to the datain method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] a = new String[x];
    double[] b = new double[x];

    new DatainTest().datain(a, b);
}

public void datain(String[] a, double[] b) {
    System.out.println("Valor test:" + b[0]);
}
```

I assume that `DatainTest` is the name of your class.

Maybe you can provide more information of what you are trying to do, because there are many different approaches to pass data to a method and choosing the right one is highly dependent on your goal.

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
public static void datain(double[] b) {
//...
```

then you can do this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
    [...] 
    String[] a = new String[x];
    double[] b = new double[x];
    datain(b);
    [...]
}
```